# Traversing through JSON with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grab an image link from an XML file to display. But I'm having difficulty traversing through the converted JSON file.

Scenario: I have the following XML file where I'm trying to grab X.

```
<channel>
   <image>...</image>
   <item>...</item>
   <item>
      <title></title>
      <description></description>
      <media:content url="X"></media:content>
   </item>
   <item>...</item>
</channel>
```

I've converted it to JSON using a plugin. Then, I stored it in a variable:

```
const valueJson = $.xml2json(f1);
```

Then I'm randomizing which contents of `<item></item>` I pull

```
let itemDisplay = Math.floor(Math.random() * valueJson.channel.item.length);
```

Through the following line, I'm able to pull the value contained within title and description and display it on the page:

```
$("#div1").html("<div style='text-align: center'>" + valueJson.channel.item[itemDisplay].title + "</div>" + "<div>" + valueJson.channel.item[itemDisplay].description + "</div>");
```

But when I try to do the same for the image, I get an Uncaught TypeError

```
$("#div2").html(valueJson.find("url")[itemDisplay]);
```

I also tried this:

```
$("#div2").html(valueJson.channel.item[itemDisplay].media.url);
```

But that also doesn't work

Clearly, I'm traversing the JSON object array incorrectly. Any tips?

Comment: Please show a small sample of `valueJson`.

Comment: Why does `find("url")` have `[itemDisplay]` on the end? I thought `url` was "X"? Also, what error do you get specifically?

Comment: `find()` is for searching the DOM, not regular JS objects and arrays.

Comment: Why not send the object to console to see what parameters are there. `console.log(valueJson.channel.item[1])`